# Why running kotlin tests so slow in AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

When I updated project to AndroidStudio 3 unit tests became runnig slowly (about 6 mimutes) than AndroidStudio 2. Recently, I updated project to AndroidStudio3.1, but test running time stayed the same.

Comment: What's you configuration? What's the gradle.build? How does it relate to kotlin? What were the previous test times?

Comment: Nothig special, simple android plugin, simple kotlin plugin... Previous test running time is about 1 minute. I run tests by clicking icon near test class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37028496#comment11) in Android Studio 3.1 RC. There is workaround for previous studio versions: manually create an AndroidJUnit configuration.

Answer (score 3):

It's a (now) known issue for Kotlin in AS 3
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37028496
This happens because AS calls the assemble* tasks (which build up the APK) for kotlin unit tests.

Comment: Ok, Temporary solution for fast running Kotlin AndroidJUnit tests: manually add AndroidJUnit run configuration